# Can I Update NetCraft DNS info?

Tags: domain-name-system, update, whois

http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://elementsystems.net

It has the wrong "Organisation", "Nameserver Organisation" and "Reverse DNS"

My domain information is private and from what I can see, everything on my server is setup correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is setup in the registries whois records, contact your registry (godaddy) for them to update it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, Netcraft will remove the information from their website if you contact them (support@netcraft.com) but they will not amend it for you. As mentioned in the other answer @topdog, this information is already available elsewhere in the public domain so contacting Netcraft to remove it is as useful as chasing a goose.

Comment: Goose chasing is good exercise, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input, a very helpful answer to improve my understanding of the web and all of its dark corners.